# ROR -- NoMethodError in Carts#show -- Private Method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, private, nomethoderror

I am currently following the Agile Web Development book (Rails 3) and have been stuck with a Private Method error. After hours of research I have not been able to find a solution.

The following is the code I'm working with and have discovered the string giving the problem is:

```
<td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
```

There is a similar problem/solution that has been posted where the solution was to place the line Item class above the private, however, the line item class is not private.

Any help would be appreciated.

CODE

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<table>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.quantity %>&times;</td>
      <td><%= item.product.title %></td>
      <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  <% end %>
 <!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
</table>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->

<%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, method: :delete,
     data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Error

```
private method `total_price' called for #<LineItem
```

line_item model

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id
end

def total_price
    product.price * quantity
end
```

cart model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
     current_item
  end

  def total_price
     line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
   end
end
```

line item controller

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
   def index
     @line_items = LineItem.all

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @line_items }
    end
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @line_item }
    end
  end

   # GET /line_items/new
   # GET /line_items/new.json
  def new
     @line_item = LineItem.new

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # new.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @line_item }
     end
   end

   # GET /line_items/1/edit
   def edit
     @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
   end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
   def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
    @line_item.product = product

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
           notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item,
          status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
         format.html { render action: "new" }
         format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
         status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

   # PUT /line_items/1
   # PUT /line_items/1.json
   def update
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update_attributes(params[:line_item])
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
         format.html { render action: "edit" }
         format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
     end
   end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller?

Comment: please provide your model side code (file having `total_price` method)?

Comment: Thanks Robert and Salil. I have included controller and model code to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `LineItem` model `total_price` is defined outside of the `LineItem` class. So it should be:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Casual Coder, that was the solution. Thanks everyone for help, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that `@cart.total_price` is giving the error but your error showing that it is looking this function in `LineItem` model. It probably means you must have a `total_price` method in `LineItem` model also. Do you have that? And yes as others said, it would be better to add your controller and model codes in your post.

***Edit:***

Based on your update in the post, yes the `total_price` method should be inside in your class. does that solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Samiron. Sorry, I pasted the wrong string, it should have been:

    'code'<td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>